# Outlook have security problems

Tags: windows, security, outlook

I'm using Outlook 2013 as client with a gmail account.
The OS is Windows 10.
I received some emails which I cannot open from Outlook (although from Gmail have no problems). The message which I get when I double click the email is this:

> Sorry, we're having trouble opening this item. This could be temporary, but if you see it again you might want to restart Outlook. An error occurred in the underlying security system. An internal error occurred.

I searched in system logs and I found that Outlook has a problem notified there. I'll try to describe it bellow:

module OUTLMIME.DLL, which is loaded by OUTLOOK.EXE has a problem, having exception code 0xc0000005.

Due to this problem, after I start Outlook, I get the following logs, from "Software Protection service" or Security-SPP:

1. The Software Protection service is starting.
   Parameters:caller=OUTLOOK.EXE
2. Initialization status for service objects.
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sppwinob.dll, msft:spp/windowsfunctionality/agent/7.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:rm/algorithm/inherited/1.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:rm/algorithm/phone/1.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:rm/algorithm/pkey/detect, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:spp/ActionScheduler/1.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:spp/TaskScheduler/1.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:spp/statecollector/pkey, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:spp/volume/services/kms/1.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:spp/volume/services/kms/activationinfo/1.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
3. The Software Protection service has completed licensing status check. ...
4. The Software Protection service has started. ...

And this start again and again, because the error above occurs. If I close Outlook this happens no more.

Can anybody help me in solving this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade Outlook to the latest version? We had something similar in the previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be Software Protection Service related. It's just doing what it should do when an application starts.

Try to start Outlook in safe mode first, see if the issue is caused by any add-ins. If issue persists, try to setup the mailbox on another Outlook client or mailbox application, check the result.

Also, compare these affected items with other normal mail items, maybe all of these affected items include some specific objects\links\attachments\etc..

Comment: How to start Outlook in safe mode?

Comment: [I googled it and got this as first link](https://www.outlook-tips.net/beginner-user/start-outlook-in-safe-mode/)

Comment: @artaxerxe  Yes, just run outlook.exe /safe in the Start Search or Run box will start Outlook in safe mode.